# How to deal with nested transactions in EF7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I know that EF7 doesn't support `TransactionScope` anymore.
I also know how to do an explicit `BeginTransaction()`.
What I'm struggling with now is situations where a code path may create a nested transaction.

`TransactionScope` handled this situation very cleanly; the explicit `BeginTransaction()` does not.

Are there any recommended practices for dealing with the possibility of nested transactions?